# Show on blog posts from users

Tags: wordpress

I'm doing a WordPress theme and I have "Share your story" page, where everybody can write his story (like a comment, filling fields like name, story, url etc).

Then, after an administrator will check that post it will automatically appear on another page in same blog. So far I haven't found any kind of plugin or somebody else to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a function i built i couple of weeks ago.

```
function contribute() {
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

// Create post object
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
     'post_content' => $_POST['content'],
     'post_status' => 'pending',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'post_category' => 'catergory_id',
     'ping_status' => 'open'
  );

// Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );

}
$title = 'Title';
$content = 'Content';
?>

 <form method="post" id="contribute" action="">

<input name="title" type="textarea" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" onblur="if (this.value == '')  
{this.value = '<?php echo $title; ?>';}"  
onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php echo $title; ?>')  
{this.value = '';}" style="width: 350px; border: #000 1px solid; padding: 10px;"  />   <br />
<textarea name="content" rows="9" cols="45" style="width: 350px; height: 200px; border: #000 1px solid; padding: 10px; "> <?php echo $content;?> 
</textarea> <br />
<div style="margin-top: 10px">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="<?php _e('Send') ?>" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; color: white; background: black; padding: 10px; border: #000 1px solid;" />
</div>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for time you spent to help me. I've read something about wp_inster_post() function, but not enough to catch entire idea. In few hours i'm going to try your code and then you'll have a feedback. Again, thanks.

Comment: Hi again sir. Your function works great, but right now i have another problem. Instead of your form i use a wordpress plugin , Contact Form 7. By default, this plugin sends the message to an specified email address, but using it i want to send the content according to your function (To be more precise, i want send a post using that plugin). Do you have any idea about this issue? Regards

Comment: hey,just replace all "send" with a another text, like "cont".